# Cant make JSON/PHP echo message appear using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to make a PHP echo messages show up whenever users inputs either nothing at all or no numbers. Ive been able to make error messages show up when someone doesnt input numbers onto the text field.

However I cant make the error message I've created in PHP to show up whenever someone clicks the send button without inputing anything at all in the text field.

My PHP code:

```
$resurs    = array();
$fyll = $_GET['inputfield'];
$dg = 2; 
$nummer1      = $nummer1 * $dg;
$fel = "Fill in a number";
$nummer2      = $nummer1 * $fill;
$no = "Field is empty";

if (is_numeric($fyll)){

$resurs = array(
    "nummer1" => $nummer1. "<br>",
    "nummer2" => $nummer2. "<br>"

);

echo json_encode($resurs);

    }

else {
    $resurs = array (
    "fel" => $fel. "<br>"
    );

echo json_encode ($resurs);
}          

if (empty($fyll)){
    $resurs = array (
    "no" => $no. "<br>"
    );
     echo json_encode ($resurs);
}
```

My Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit1").click(function(){
    var siffra = document.getElementById("inputfield");
        $.getJSON("form.php?inputfield="+siffra.value, function(result){
var t1;
var t2;
var t3;
var error;          

          $.each(result, function(i, field){

                if (i =="nummer1"){
                t1 = field
                }

                if (i == "nummer2"){
                t2 = field
                }

                if (i == "no"){
                t3 = field
                }

                if (i == "fel"){
                error = field
                }               
                $(".d1").html(t1);
                $(".d2").html(t2);
                $(".d3").html(t3);
                $(".d3").html(error);
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `field` will be an object. You need to retrieve the properties of that object. So either, `field.nummer1`, `field.nummer2`, `field.fel` or `field.no` depending on the response from the request

Answer (score 0):

`field` will be an object. You need to retrieve the properties of that object. So either, `field.nummer1`, `field.nummer2`, `field.fel` or `field.no` depending on the response from the request. Try this:

```
$.each(result, function (i, field) {
    if (i == "nummer1")
        t1 = field.nummer1;

    if (i == "nummer2")
        t2 = field.nummer2;

    if (i == "no")
        t3 = field.no;

    if (i == "fel")
        error = field.fel;

    $(".d1").html(t1);
    $(".d2").html(t2);
    $(".d3").html(t3);
    $(".d3").html(error);
});
```

Note that you're setting the value of each `.dX` element in each iteration of the loop, even when there is no value for the variable provided. I would suggest you check the logic of this function against your requirements.

Comment: I can already make t1, t2 and error work. But for some reason t3 does not work, even when I apply your code it doesnt work.